# Chapter 4 of Learning Core Audio not working due to AudioQueueNewInput failing with fmt?

Tags: ios, macos, core-audio

I am trying to get the Recording program from Chapter 4 of Learning Core Audio by Adamson and Avila to work.  Both typing it in by hand and the unmodified version downloaded from the informit website fail in the same way.  It always fails with this at the point of queue creation.

```
Error: AudioQueueNewInput failed ('fmt?')
```

Has anyone else tried this sample program on Mavericks and XCode5?  Here's the one from the download site up to the point of failure.  When I tried LPCM with some hardcoded parameters, then it's ok but I cannot get MPEG4AAC to work.  Seems like AppleLossless works though.

```
// Code from download
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
MyRecorder recorder = {0};
AudioStreamBasicDescription recordFormat = {0};
memset(&recordFormat, 0, sizeof(recordFormat));

// Configure the output data format to be AAC
recordFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
recordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;

// get the sample rate of the default input device
// we use this to adapt the output data format to match hardware capabilities
MyGetDefaultInputDeviceSampleRate(&recordFormat.mSampleRate);

// ProTip: Use the AudioFormat API to trivialize ASBD creation.
//         input: at least the mFormatID, however, at this point we already have
//                mSampleRate, mFormatID, and mChannelsPerFrame
//         output: the remainder of the ASBD will be filled out as much as possible
//                 given the information known about the format
UInt32 propSize = sizeof(recordFormat);
CheckError(AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_FormatInfo, 0, NULL,
                                  &propSize, &recordFormat), "AudioFormatGetProperty failed");

// create a input (recording) queue
AudioQueueRef queue = {0};
CheckError(AudioQueueNewInput(&recordFormat, // ASBD
                              MyAQInputCallback, // Callback
                              &recorder, // user data
                              NULL, // run loop
                              NULL, // run loop mode
                              0, // flags (always 0)
                              // &recorder.queue), // output: reference to AudioQueue object
                              &queue),
           "AudioQueueNewInput failed");
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced up with same problem. Check the sample rate. In your case it will be huge (96000). Just try to set it manually to 44100.